# pandas.errors.ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 9996 and found 9808

Tags: python, pandas

When I use pandas to process my data, here is an error like title. My data's column is not equivalent, So I sort it in an descending order. The first line is the longest and next line is shorter and so on. When the file is small, pandas can process it successfully. But after I write all my data in the file, it can't process and show me this error.

here is my code:

```
def sequencein(filepath):    
    print (filepath)    
    print("time", time.time())    
    data = pd.read_table(filepath, header=None)    
    print("time", time.time())    
    matr = data.values    
    print("sequence shape:", matr.shape)    
    return matr
```

file's end of the line is shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBLVD.png)

Comment: Are you sure this is the source of the error?

Comment: Yes, and now I have solved this problem, I add a header with 9996 columns and then it worked. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 13):

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) says there are two engines:

> engine : {‘c’, ‘python’}, optional
>
> Parser engine to use. The C engine is faster while the python engine is currently more feature-complete.

The problem seems to appear only with the 'c' engine, which is selected automatically for larger files.

So, you could try

```
data = pd.read_table(filepath, header=None, engine='python')
```

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this problem by myself. I just modified `data = pd.read_table(filepath, header=None)` to `data = pd.read_table(filepath)`. Then I added a header line in my data file and it worked.

Comment: I also had the header issue, but my data was correct. This is more like work-around. The Python pandas package has a bug.